# How do I stretch a replacement drain hose to fit over the existing pipe?

Tags: washing-machine

The original drain hose needed to be replaced, but the new hose is the same size as the existing pipe.  What is the trick for "stretching" the hose over the pipe before reattaching the clamps?

Comment: Is the new hose you have perhapps meant to be inserted into a standpipe?

Comment: What sort of hose or what's this for? Why is the new hose different from the old? Pictures may help

Comment: Second the request for pictures.  No idea what the context of your question involves.

Answer (score 1):

Spit, determination and super human powers.  You might put a little soap and water (very little) on the inside to help but wait a day before using the washer.  Don't forget the clamps.  That would be bad. Very bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a rubber coupling with a hose clamp on each end. This will allow you to couple two pipes or tubings of the same size to each other. These are used all the time on PVC drain pipes for repairs. Since there is no water pressure on a drain line, they will not leak if tightened properly.